# How does link with href for Line and Wechat?

Tags: wechat

Do you know the protocol for Line and Wechat? I want to find link of Line and Wechat like yahoo(ymsgr:sendIM?userid) and skype(skype:userid?chat)

Answer (score 2):

The protocol you are looking for is weixin://

We are currently aware of 2 different ways to call this:

1. weixin://contacts/profile/USERNAME - USERNAME is a variable
2. weixin://qr/DECODED_QR_CODE - DECODED_QR_CODE is the decoded version of a WeChat QR code.

*** IMPORTANT NOTE: Please note this functionality has been deprecated***

Comment: @DeveloperX Would you know if there is a new way to handle these links as of today?

Comment: @Developerx , trying to implement server configuration using python. it's saying token verification failed. can u help with it ?