# How to logout from WeChat programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wechat

I want to logout programatically from wechat just like we do in Facebook and Twitter.
Is it possible?

Righty now I have successfully integrated the wechat into my application using [WeChat SDK](http://dev.wechat.com/wechatapi/installguide), but when I am pressing the share button (in my application) to share the image on wechat then I am redirected to the wechat application and then after successful uploading return to my application.

But is it possible to stop being redirected to WeChat application? I just simply want to share image without redirect to WeChat application. And also how to share multiple image in once on WeChat?

Comment: [pragmatically?](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pragmatically)

Comment: Isn't there any Controller like MFMailComposeViewController in WeChat SDK? Just share from right within the app...

Comment: Hi Can you tell me how can I login with using we chat and get user information in my iPhone application?

Comment: aksh can you please share your code for which you successfully integrated the wechat into my application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be its works for you..

```
 -(void) weChatDidLogout
        {
            NSLog(@"Logged out of wechat");
            NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
            NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
            for (cookie in [storage cookies])
            {
                NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
                NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"wechat"];
                if(domainRange.length > 0)
                {
                    [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `WeChat SDK` does not provide a way in which could share something without redirect to `WeChat`.

This is because the share function of `WeChat` does not store any user credential (like OAuth) in your app locally, so it need to redirect every time to know who want to share.